# Google Map not running on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to run google map on android application I have used Debug certificate fingerprint and my package name to get API KEY when I run the application on emulator I got this error

```
Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is 
probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

while getting bank screen in the emulator attached below, I'm sure is everything is correct from my side

1. Activate Maps SDK for Android
2. Get Debug certificate fingerprint using

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey - storepass android -keypass android
   ```
3. Add the API key into res/value/google_maps_api.xml

could you please help in that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue I was using handleSSLHandShake in android app class it's working fine after removing it.

```
    public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((arg0, arg1) -> {
            Log.e("verify_url","is => "+arg0);
            if(arg0.equals("") ){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```